# Label with selectable text

Tags: python, kivy

i'm trying to create chatbox on kivy python. one of the most difficult is to create class with super class Label, which can support select its text like a TextInput class. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not in an appropriate form for StackOverflow. It would be far easier for us to answer questions posted more concretely. Could you show the code you have written and perhaps which exact constructs you are having a problem with?

Comment: sorry, it's my first question, i have not the code for this class, becose i dont't know with what start this. I try to inherit TextInput from Label, but it is impossible

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a TextInput field?  change the appearance parameters so it looks like a label and disable input to the field.

Comment: this's good advice, i'll see the documentation. But if i'm rigth, then a can't do for example rounded corners for it